# Multiple charts of clustered columns for multiple entries in a spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a large Excel spreadsheet with data from multiple locations, delivery time and collection time of packages.

I am interested in producing clustered column graphs for each location, with monthly count of the packages received and delivered. This is a sample of the section of interest from the spreadsheet.

| Location | Delivered | Collected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | 01/09/2021 | 05/09/2021 |
| London | 01/09/2021 | 03/09/2021 |
| Denver | 04/09/2021 | 05/09/2021 |
| Denver | 04/10/2021 | 01/11/2021 |
| Denver | 11/11/2021 | 12/12/2021 |

The graph for each location should have each month on the horizontal axis, from Sep 2020 to Sep 2021 and should have the count on the vertical axis, displaying two vertical bars for each month, representing the count of delivered and the count of collected on that month. Example:

[image]

Also, is there a neater way to create a chart to just easily filter by location and instantly produce the graph for each location?

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: I don't see a question either...

Comment: The question is about how to produce the graphs

Comment: @Joe Does my suggestion work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the Excel Power Query to unpivot your data first.

Step 1, Select your dara range > Right-click it > Get Data from Table/Range.

[image]

Step 2, select 2 columns, Delivered and Collected > Right-click > Unpivot Columns.

[image]

Step 3, close and load this query, then create a pivot table as following.

[image]

Step 4, right-click the data value in pivot table > Group > Choose by Months and Years.

[image]

Step 5, crteat the pivot table chart. You may choose different location via filter.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Emily, that was very helpful, clear and concise